# How to paste value with over 15 decimal places into Access table field?

Tags: ms-access

I have value as such:

0.0252947874381181000000

I need to copy this value from excel spreadsheet into Access local table. The field type is Double, decimal places are set to Auto. I am getting the following message: The value you entered isn't valid for this field. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is wrong is simply, that Double can't handle that many decimals.

Change the data type to *Decimal*.

Comment: yeah.. It is not even that... one of the other fields should have 'Text' instead of 'Number' type. Well, I guess I should be more detailed.

Comment: Well, we only have your example, and Decimal can hold `0.0252947874381181000000` or `0.0252947874381181000009`.